# Create test for rest post method using mock object

Tags: rest, testing, post, mockito

i have post method in rest controller and i want to create a test for this method:
This is my method:

```
@PostMapping("/persons")
public ResponseEntity<PersonDto> createPerson(@RequestBody PersonDto personDto) {
    try {
        personService.createPerson(personDto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(personDto);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
}
```

I have no idea how this test with mock should look like.

Answer (score 0):

As you use Spring, I recommend you to use `@WebMvcTest` to mock all things but the Controller under test.
You should so explicitly mock the dependencies of this Controller. In your case, mocking the `personService` field is enough.
In your test class declare a `personService` field annotated with `@MockBean` to create a Mockito mock of the class that will be added to the Spring context.
Then record a behavior for this mock.
You have two branches here : it works and an exception is risen. 
So you could define two test method and record a specific behavior in each one.
At last assert the gotten response from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I already have test for deleting method. Yes i use springboot, jpa, rest, h2:

```
@Test
public void shouldDeletePersonById() throws Exception {
    Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(personService).deleteById(1L);
    mockMvc.perform(delete("/persons/{id}", 1L)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
}
```

But for create person this looks for me very hard. I don't know what i should call of in posy method(like in delete i call id to find what i want to delete).